# Cakephp 3 Field that should be a date

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Okay I have a database from a third party vendor that stores the dates as julian dates. I am trying to find an easier way for the other developers to use CakePHP 3 ORM as it is so that they can pass into the where statement like such.

```
$date = new DateTime('NOW');
$query->find()->where(['created'=>$date];
```

Right now the created field is stored as an integer with the day of the year and year appended together as one number. Would I just create a custom database type and it will automatically convert the date to julian? OR should I do this some other way??

Comment: That would be the way to go, yes. Of course you could also convert the data in a more useful format.

Comment: I can't adjust the database at all. I figured the way to go about it would be the custom database types in cakephp3